# write structure to text file / write values from text file back into the structure (VB.net)

Tags: vb.net, structure

What I want to do is write a structure to a text file, let some program do its work (which also writes a text file) and write some values back into the structure.

I hope it gets clear what I want to do.

```
Module NavigateStruct
    Structure longStructure
        Dim a As String
        Dim b As nestedStructure
        Structure nestedStructure
            Dim c As Double
            Dim d As nestednestedStructure
            Structure nestednestedStructure
                Dim e As Integer
            End Structure
        End Structure
    End Structure
```

`Sub navigateStructure()
    Dim myStruct As longStructure
    myStruct.b.c = 5.0

    ' somthing read from the text file
    Dim str As String = "b-c"
    Dim val1 As Double = 15.0

    Dim val2 As Double

    Dim splt() As String = str.Split(CChar("-"))
    ' splt ={"b", "c"}

    ' some Code to navigate to and set or retrieve value
    ' (use values in splt as fieldname)
    ' retrieve (that's not how it actually works, only something in simple pseudo code. Is there a way to write it in 'real' VB.net?)
    val2=myStruct.[splt(0)].[splt(1)]
    ' set   (pseudo code as well, but how does it work?)
    myStruct.[splt(0)].[splt(1)] = val1

    ' val2 = 5
    ' myStruct.b.c = 15

End Sub

Sub writeStructureToString()

    ' some code running thru all elements of the structure including nested ones and writing 'parentname'-'childname'   value

    ' result
    ' str = "a  something"
    '       "b-c    5.0"
    '       "d-e    0"
    '       "...    ..."
End Sub`

End Module

Comment: What is the question? Is there an issue, and if so what?

Comment: You could save yourself a lot of time and trouble if you serialized the data rather than converting to string to save as text

Comment: Hi @Plutonix, what does serializing mean? I have read it on some answers to questions in context but I don't get how it's done.

Comment: serializing is converting an object (like longStructure) to some notation (often text) which allows it to be transferred, saved etc.  The object can be recreated from that data later or elsewhere.  Binary, XML and JSON are the most common forms/formats